# Replace Impute Resample values in a dataframe column(s) on a condition in Python

Tags: python, replace, time-series, resampling, imputation

I have a time series sensor data.  Each column (SENSOR1, SENSOR2, …) has sensor readings values and also ‘Not in Service’ as 'Serv', ‘Fail’, ‘Config’. They needs to be replaced with smth meaningful.

How to replace **values in one column** based on a different condition, i.e., ‘Serv’ replace with 'ffill' python function, ‘Fail’ replace with 0, ‘Config’ replace with median.

The challenging part is that each sensor has to be treated separately, say measure of unit for sensor1 is BARG, for Sensor2 is %, for Sensor3 is temperature.

this is the logic, but I know the implementation is not correct…

```
sensor1replace = {
  'Serv': method = 'ffill',
  ‘Fail’: 0,
  ‘Config’: median
}
df['sensor1'].replace(sensor1replace, inplace=True)
```

I really appreciate your help. So far no solution in Google :(

its a huge file, so I made up only a sample

```
filepath = "/Users/...../Downloads/Replacement_TestData.xlsx" 

if filepath.endswith(".csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=";")
elif filepath.endswith(".xls") or filepath.endswith(".xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(filepath)

df

                        sensor1 sensor2 sensor3 sensor4
0   2019-01-14 00:00:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
1   2019-01-14 00:01:00 69.18   2.3 2162    3
2   2019-01-14 00:02:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
3   2019-01-14 00:03:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
4   2019-01-14 00:04:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
5   2019-01-14 00:05:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
6   2019-01-14 00:06:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
7   2019-01-14 00:07:00 Serv    Serv    Serv    2
8   2019-01-14 00:08:00 Serv    Serv    Serv    2
9   2019-01-14 00:09:00 Serv    Serv    2162    4
10  2019-01-14 00:10:00 Serv    Serv    2162    3
11  2019-01-14 00:11:00 Serv    Serv    2162    2
12  2019-01-14 00:12:00 Serv    Serv    2162    3
13  2019-01-14 00:13:00 69.17   2.3 2162    2
14  2019-01-14 00:14:00 69.17   2.3 2162    3
15  2019-01-14 00:15:00 69.17   2.3 2162    2
16  2019-01-14 00:16:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
17  2019-01-14 00:17:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
18  2019-01-14 00:18:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
19  2019-01-14 00:19:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
20  2019-01-14 00:20:00 69.18   2.3 2162    4
21  2019-01-14 00:21:00 Fail    Fail    Fail    Fail
22  2019-01-14 00:22:00 Fail    Fail    Fail    Fail
23  2019-01-14 00:23:00 Fail    Fail    Fail    Fail
24  2019-01-14 00:24:00 Fail    Fail    Fail    Fail
25  2019-01-14 00:25:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
26  2019-01-14 00:26:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
27  2019-01-14 00:27:00 69.18   2.3 2162    3
28  2019-01-14 00:28:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
29  2019-01-14 00:29:00 69.18   2.3 2162    3
30  2019-01-14 00:30:00 Config  2.3 2162    2
31  2019-01-14 00:31:00 Config  2.3 2162    2
32  2019-01-14 00:32:00 Config  2.3 2162    3
33  2019-01-14 00:33:00 69.18   2.3 2162    5
34  2019-01-14 00:34:00 69.18   2.3 2162    6
35  2019-01-14 00:35:00 69.18   2.3 2162    4
36  2019-01-14 00:36:00 69.18   2.3 2162    2
```

Comment: Please paste actual lines from the sample file here, not a link to a photo. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54886379/edit) button, no need to answer in the comments.

Comment: Hi Sveta, welcome on So? Could you please  produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)? Or if you could just add the output of `df.head(10).to_dict()` to your question will be great.